# jQuery append string to url after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am adding query string to urls using this jQuery

```
$( 'a' ).attr( 'href', function(index, value) {
return value + '?appp=3';
});
```

This works fine, but after the ajax load, the new href's created are not recognized by the above jQuery. Is there a way to reload the code so to affect the new posts URL's which are loaded via ajax. Super thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hm, can you write the code what you did?

Comment: create a function and put the above mentioned code inside that function. Call that function on DOM ready as well as after ajax load completes the DOM population.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually here is my final code which is better version in case the URL already appended a query should anyone might find useful:

```
function apendquery() {
    $('a').attr('href', function(index, value) {
        return value + (value.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?") + 'appp=3';
    });
};

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    apendquery();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, thanks @developer, that worked nicely. Here how I did it as you mentioned:

```
 function apendquery(){
 $( 'a' ).attr( 'href', function(index, value) {
 return value + '?appp=3';
 });
 };


 $(document).ready(function(){
 apendquery();
 });

 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
 apendquery();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it wont work on new elements. You can create function which you shuold call each time when new 'a' elements appears in DOM. Also you will need to create some kind of flag which helps you identify and update the href only for the new elements.

```
var updateHref = function(){
   $( 'a[data-updated!=1]' ).attr( 'data-updated',1).attr( 'href',   
    function(index, value) {
      return value + '?appp=3';
    }); 
};
...
$.ajax(...)
 .done(function() { 
  ...
  // add new 'a' tags
  ....
  // then call our function to update href
  updateHref();
});
```